# How to launch Chromium 99.0.4844.51 for Linux?

Tags: linux

im using Unbuntu 64 bit on WmWare Virtual Machine. I have downloaded Chromium 99.0.4844.51 for Linux from https://chromium.cypress.io/linux/stable/99.0.4844.51. The problem is that i don't know how to start the application. Is there any command that i need to execute in the terminal?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using either `apt install chromium-browser` or downloading from chromium.org? In any case, using `chromium-browser` from the command line should launch the browser.

Comment: The command chromium-browser did not work. The problem is that Chromedriver does not support the latest version  99.0.4844.84 https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The generally recommended way to install Chromium on Ubuntu is through the graphical system package manager Synaptic, or with `apt` if you prefer the command line. Among other things, this will put the `chrome` binary in your PATH, and set up shortcuts in your desktop environment.

If you want to run the version of Chromium you downloaded, first unzip the zip file and then execute the chrome binary. Assuming you downloaded it to the default Downloads directory, the following commands should execute it:

```
cd $HOME/Downloads
unzip Linux_x64_961656_chrome-linux.zip
./chrome-linux/chrome-wrapper
```

Comment: When i try to run the file  "Chrome" it says Could not display Chrome! There is not application installed for shared library files.

Comment: Please check this screenshot: https://www.bildtagg.se/bild/7cnsu72vz0ymct57af5cash

Comment: My bad. Please try running `chrome-wrapper` not `chrome` as I originally said. I also edited my post.